# bash script emails fine for SMS texts but not for MMS - MIME content seems to be boundary-isolated by cell phone company

Tags: bash, email, android, mime-types

I need my bash shell scripting to "sendmail" (ssmtp specifically) the jpg file of interest out to email clients and/or two Android "text" (MMS) clients. As long as I stay with non-MIME, non-HTML my bash scripting does get emails to email clients and SMS texts to Android clients, but we really need for the Androids to receive an MMS version having images rendered inline.  Verizon is the carrier so we are trying the @mypixmessages.com addressing with the shell script line of:

```
cat "$path"content|mail -s "$(cat "$path"subject.txt)" "$(cat "$path"recipients.txt)"
```

The sendmail program ("mail" in the above line) is actually ssmtp, in case there is some known issue about precisely which sendmail program can or cannot send to MMS correctly.  *This command line sends to SMS just fine*, albeit to a different Verizon gateway from @mypixmessages.com.  And @vzwpix.com does not output anything to our phones.

The size of the "content" file is about 19KB and looks like thus:

```
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=20200918111059657_LINE

This is a MIME encoded message. Decode it with mmunencode

--20200918111059657_LINE

Content-Type: multipart/alternative
SHOULD BE AN IMAGE DISPLAYED

--20200918111059657_LINE

Content-Type: Text/HTML; charset=US-ASCII
<html>
<body>
<img src="cid:192168011_01_20200918205038535_INTRUSION_DETECTION.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>

--20200918111059657_LINE

Content-ID: <192168011_01_20200918205038535_INTRUSION_DETECTION.jpg>
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJ
.
.  (more lines of encoding like this are here)
.
NoATtRRS0AJS0UgoAkQdTTqRBxS96AFJzxnk0UmfmyKKAP/Z

--20200918111059657_LINE--
```

Encoding into base64 is being done with mmencode.

Judging by what shows up on the cell phones, this is being enclosed in some higher level MIME content whose boundaries cordon off my own MIME content from being marked up, if you will.

Does anyone know of a solution where my content will remain as the controlling content so the images will be displayed?  But since I've never been successful at MMS, could I be making some kind of mistake in the MIME content file I build as shown above?  Or I've read that not all sendmail lookalikes produce suitable output, if that should be where to look?  An experienced set of eyes would sure be appreciated here.  Thank you for help!!!

EDIT:  (@mypixmessages.com) does correctly translate a simple gmail email (GUI is from my laptop, of course) with an inline jpg image *when I let gmail add the MIME/HTML markup to it*. So I can only conclude that ssmtp on my server (CLI) is doing something in MIME to the emails as it sends them out, like adding boundaries and/or such or that I am not getting the MIME right, that forces my MIME markup to be treated as mere text.  What makes this difficult for me to troubleshoot is that my Android doesn't allow me to view the raw MMS MIME markup language on texts received.

Comment: if you use  number@vzwpix.com instead of number@mypixmessages, what are the results

Comment: I got the same result early on, but let me try...just a sec...Waiting for it to hit my phone (did I run out of minutes?).  While I'm waiting let me say that my gmail account is one of the recipients, and it renders without marking up the same way - no image unless I would go to heroics of copy-paste and decode, I suppose.  This doesn't seem to send there.  I'll try @vtext.com and see....

Comment: @vzwpix.com does not send me anything whatsoever in response....at least for 20 mins now

Comment: My continued testing shows that the gateway/MTA (@mypixmessages.com) will correctly render a simple gmail email (GUI is from my laptop, of course) with an inline jpg image as long as I don't add any MIME/HTML markup to it.  So I can only conclude that ssmtp on my server (CLI) is doing something in MIME to the emails as it sends them out, like adding boundaries and/or such

Comment: I have gone away from using ssmtp to Michal Ludvig's smtp-cli perl script.  Although it still doesn't send out email perfect enough to satisfy Verizon @mypixmessages.com that translates to MMS to make images show up inline, it does the non-MMS job fine to gmail.  Therefore, I feel it gets me just a little closer to a solution.